# Stop variable from decrementing in canvas

Tags: javascript, variables, canvas

I am making a game and I have a simple point system based on time, where the date is stored in a variable called `start` when the level begins (I have several levels), and then when the level has ended it takes the other date stored in a variable called `stop`. Then the elapsed time is calculated in a variable called `elapsed`. Finally, the points are displayed in a final variable named `points`. The starting value is 300000 and every millisecond it decreases, reaching zero after 5 minutes (It's a short level). My only problem is that once the level is finished and the points are displayed, the points keep on decreasing. I've faced similar problems before, but I've always seemed to find a workaround since the value would be small usually. The relevant code is as such:
`start = new Date().getTime();

stop = new Date().getTime();

elapsed = stop - start;

points = 300000 - elapsed;`
all of the variables were declared before globally. In a way, It's expected, since the `points` variable is updated 1000 times per second. So, is there any way to stop it from decrementing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the value before assign the new position.

You should use `global` `var` using `window` prefix : `window.points`

```
start = new Date().getTime();
stop = new Date().getTime();
var elapsed = stop - start;
if(elapsed < 300000)
    points = 300000 - elapsed;
```